# Why does Math.min([1,2]) return NaN?

Tags: javascript

I've been debugging this code for about an hour, and it looks like `Math.min([1,2])` returns `NaN`.

```
var int_array = [1,2]
console.log(Math.min(int_array)) //prints NaN, but expect 1
isNaN(Math.min(int_array))===true
```

Comment: `console.log(Math.min.apply(Math,[1,2]))` works

Answer (score 37, accepted):

The [`Math.min()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/min) function actually expects a series of numbers, but it doesn't know how to handle an actual array, so it is blowing up.

You can resolve this by using the [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator) `...`:

```
var int_array = [1,2];
console.log(Math.min(...int_array)); // returns 1
```

You could also accomplish this via the [`Function.apply()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) function that would essentially do the same thing but isn't as pretty :

```
var int_array = [1,2];
console.log(Math.min.apply(null,int_array)); // returns 1
```

Comment: God that's annoying behavior - this is still a thing in 2023.

Answer (score 5):

You pass an array as first parameter to `min` function

```
Math.min([1,2])
```

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/min)

> If at least one of arguments cannot be converted to a number, the result is NaN.

Answer (score 0):

This

```
var int_array = [1,2];
console.log(Math.min.apply(null,int_array));
```

will work in all actual browsers.